# ajax data sent wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

below is an ajax but it wont work, what seems be the problem? assume that I have requestparser.php and inside it i have "echo "yes ajax work!";".

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // start ajax form submission
    $.ajax({
    url: "requestparser.php",
    type:"POST",
    data: ({ "pulldata" : "oy" }),
    success:function(e){
        if(($.trim(e)=="success")){
            alert("yes");
        }else{
            alert("no");     
        }
    },error:function(){
       alert("error");
    }
   }); 
});
```

as above ajax function ,the process should be, on load it will send first a post request to requestparser.php with a post name of "pulldata" and post content of "oy" and when the requestparser receive that post request from the ajax so then respond with "yes ajax work!" and since the respond from requestparser.php is not equal to success then it should display "no".

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: missing a '/' before your `requestparser.php` ? Also, your data doesn't need to be wrapped in `( )`

Comment: You're expecting to get a *"success"* message in AJAX success callback. So do `echo "success";` then in PHP.

Comment: thank you for your respond. this has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug your code and it worked fine for me. So can you try this code and say what error it shows ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({
            "pulldata": "oy"
        }),
        success: function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    });
});
```

`test.php`

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

One more thing, just for confirmation, you have included jQuery in your page before using ajax right ?